# replacing quotes inside a pandas df to count unique terms

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am reading an excel file using pandas, that contains items like this in each "firms" column:

```
'B Of A M L, Dougherty & Co., Goldman Sachs, Raymond James'
'Zacks Small Cap'
'Wedbush Securit'
'B Of A M L, Cowen & Company, Deutsche Bk Sec, Fbr Cap Markets, J.P. Morgan'
'Janney Mont., Jefferies & Co., Leerink Partner'
```

My df looks like this:

```
    firms
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   Benchmark Compa, Brean Capital, Noble Financia...
4   Fig Partners
5   Raymond James
6   Keefe Bruyette
7   Fbr Cap Markets, Fig Partners, Keefe Bruyette,...
8   Stifel Nicolaus, William Blair
9   NaN
```

I am trying to obtain a unique list of firms and pass to a python list, so I do the following:

```
unique_firms = df.firms.unique()
```

However, after doing that and after transforming to a python list to inspect the contents of the array

```
unique_firms.tolist()
```

I get (partial output):

```
[nan,
 u'Benchmark Compa, Brean Capital, Noble Financial, Northcoast Rese',
 u'Fig Partners',
 u'Raymond James',
 u'Keefe Bruyette',
 u'Fbr Cap Markets, Fig Partners, Keefe Bruyette, Raymond James',
 u'Stifel Nicolaus, William Blair',
 u'Macquarie Capit, Morgan Stanley, William Blair',
 u'Barclays Capita, Craig-Hallum, Deutsche Bk Sec, William Blair',
 u'Co Forecst, Gabelli & Compa, Keybanc Cap Mkt, Northcoast Rese',
 u'Co Forecst',
 u'Ascendiant Cap, Zacks Small Cap',
 u'B Of A M L, Feltl & Company, Piper Jaffray, Raymond James, Stifel Nicolaus',
 u'B Of A M L, Benchmark Compa, Jefferies & Co., Morgan Stanley, Piper Jaffray, Raymond James, William Blair',
 u'Baird R W, Global Hunter S, Ladenberg Thalm, Stifel Nicolaus, Suntrust Robins, Wunderlich Res',
```

Bo Of A M L and others are repeated, so my code is not choosing the unique terms. Is there are way to create a new pandas or numpy array that contains the unique terms that are comma separated in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your example, I see that you have a bunch of NaN, which you need to deal with first:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

This is a very important step, which was omitted in the previous solutions proposed. The next step is what other users have suggested:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.firms.str.split(',').tolist())
firms = df2.stack().unique().tolist()
```

This should produce a list of firms, and that’s where the other explanations stopped.  If you inspect carefully, there are some trailing spaces in the beginning of the string, so:

```
' Dougherty & Co.',
```

Would count as a separate entity from:

```
'Dougherty & Co.',
```

The next step is necessary to create your unique list of firms, and this is another reason why I think the other solutions have not worked:

```
clean_list = []
for firm in firms:
    firm = firm.strip()
    if firm not in clean_list:
        clean_list.append(firm)
    clean_list.sort()

clean_list
['B Of A M L',
 'Cowen & Company',
 'Deutsche Bk Sec',
 'Dougherty & Co.',
 'Fbr Cap Markets',
 'Goldman Sachs',
 'J.P. Morgan',
 'Janney Mont.',
 'Jefferies & Co.',
 'Leerink Partner',
 'Raymond James',
 'Wedbush Securit',
 'Zacks Small Cap']
```

Answer (score 1):

I start with

```
In[141]: df
Out[141]: 
                                               firms
0  B Of A M L, Dougherty & Co., Goldman Sachs, Ra...
1                                    Zacks Small Cap
2                                    Wedbush Securit
3  B Of A M L, Cowen & Company, Deutsche Bk Sec, ...
```

It's quite funny that I'm doing almost the same practice for two questions today now. Also here, your data structure is messed up, as you have separate entries inside the same column (separated with commas). We first fix that:

```
In[144]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.firms.str.split(',').tolist())
In[145]: df2
Out[145]: 
                 0                 1                 2                 3  \
0       B Of A M L   Dougherty & Co.     Goldman Sachs     Raymond James   
1  Zacks Small Cap              None              None              None   
2  Wedbush Securit              None              None              None   
3       B Of A M L   Cowen & Company   Deutsche Bk Sec   Fbr Cap Markets   
4     Janney Mont.   Jefferies & Co.   Leerink Partner              None   

              4  
0          None  
1          None  
2          None  
3   J.P. Morgan  
4          None
```

Now we can simply do

```
In[148]: df2.stack().unique().tolist()
Out[148]: 
['B Of A M L',
 ' Dougherty & Co.',
 ' Goldman Sachs',
 ' Raymond James',
 'Zacks Small Cap',
 'Wedbush Securit',
 ' Cowen & Company',
 ' Deutsche Bk Sec',
 ' Fbr Cap Markets',
 ' J.P. Morgan',
 'Janney Mont.',
 ' Jefferies & Co.',
 ' Leerink Partner']
```

Comment: @LMNYC, it is possible that the DataFrame you are starting with does not match exactly what FooBar put here - if the `df2` you create looks just like it does shown here, I can confirm that the second part works.